# Rewrite URL in Kubernetes with Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am migrating legacy websites to Kubernetes, which were working on URLs like **[www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com)**, **www.app2.com,**.

As all are getting deployed in one K8s cluster so I want to use URLs like `www.myapp.com/app1` and so on. But when I access **[www.myapp.com/app1](http://www.myapp.com/app1)** it routes to **[www.myapp.com/login](http://www.myapp.com/login)** rather than **[www.myapp.com/app1/login](http://www.myapp.com/app1/login)**

**Try1:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1/?(.*)
```

I tried path: /app1(.*) but it always routes this way:

**Try2:**

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: rewrite ^(/app1)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
```

This lands me to the login page but all URLs on the page still have URLs like [www.myapp.com/page1](http://www.myapp.com/page1) or **[www.myapp.com/page2](http://www.myapp.com/page2)** rather than **[www.myapp.com/app1/page1](http://www.myapp.com/app1/page1)** or **[www.myapp.com/app1/page2](http://www.myapp.com/app1/page2)**.

It looks like I have to do something in my app, but can't we do something within ingress without changes in the app code?

**Update1:**
*ingress logs:*
In browser when i access [www.myapp.com/app1](http://www.myapp.com/app1) it prints following logs

```
[13/Aug/2020:21:19:25 +0000] "GET /app1 HTTP/2.0" 303 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36" 503 0.005 [my-ns-http-svc-80] [] x.x.x.x:80 5 0.005 303 d5da4ff09ee26c83fe67519c98f5eb50
```

and in browser it gives 404 error and in URL-bar URL is **[www.myapp.com/login](http://www.myapp.com/login)**

Comment: Could u try  /app1/(.+) instead?

Comment: @Rohit no improvement, same result

Comment: Try the options from this site. I have not tried this myself. https://www.linuxrecruit.co.uk/blog?title=Kubernetes%20Nginx%20Ingress%3A%20Traffic%20Redirect%20Using%20Annotations%20Demystified&id=132

Comment: Why don't you keep the previous hostnames, though?

Comment: @BogdanL Now we want to expose this way

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following redirect is happening in your app:

`www.myapp.com/app1` ➡️ `www.myapp.com/app1/login`

So if you'd like the same behavior in the Ingress resource you will have to remove the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` annotation.

Then on your paths, you can have something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1  Handles the initial request
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1/.*  Handles the redirect your app is doing.
```

✌️

Comment: My answer is assuming you want to hit `www.myapp.com/app1/login` and not `www.myapp.com/login` which one is it?

Comment: Yes , correct I want to hit www.myapp.com/app1/login but when I access www.myapp.com/app1 it redirect to www.myapp.com/login rather than www.myapp.com/app1/login

Comment: But in update1 you are saying that you are hitting `www.myapp.com/login`

Comment: "when I access www.myapp.com/app1 it redirect to www.myapp.com/login" That redirect seems to be coming from the application itself, so you probably need to make it aware of the extra `/app1` in the path.

Comment: Or maybe you want to hit `www.myapp.com/app1` and magically have it work with `www.myapp.com/login`? That won't work (unless you modify you app) Also, what happens when you use `app2`?  You are better off separating the domains `www.myapp1.com` and `www.myapp2.com`.