# Path on ingress reloads to error 404 until I go back to the root

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have implemented nginx ingress like below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jj-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 5000 
           .
           .
           .
```

The problem I have is that after hitting the`/` login page, although I can navigate to home page and contacts and so forth, whenever the page reloads, it gives an error 404-page not found. How do I solve that error because I don't think the solution is to explicitly write all the possible paths

Comment: You need server-side URL rewriting to support direct loading of React Router links

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Well, thanx Phil but I don't think it does, I have implemented react routing and before i migrated to k8s it worked fiine.. The issue came after deploying and using ingress.

Comment: That's because your Webpack dev server handles the rewrites for you. Have a look at [Rewrite URL in Kubernetes with Ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399078/rewrite-url-in-kubernetes-with-ingress)

Comment: I see, I attempted this before, getting rid of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` annotation .. but I don't know, do you think the order of the paths is of relevance?

Comment: Perhaphs implement some custom rules on my server blocks.. what so you think?  @Phil

Comment: I've never set this up through Ingress so can't really help directly

Comment: ooh ok .. if I may ask, how do you handle situations where you have two react apps, each should be assigned the root path `/` (like one goes to admin home another to normal user home). How do you separate the paths and their respective backends?

Comment: Never done that either. Sounds very complicated. I suppose I'd set the two apps up with their own base URLs and use the server-side URL rewriting to direct each base path to the appropriate `index.html` file